# The wordpress administrator can not change the author on the published page (not in the post)

Tags: wordpress

Good afternoon! I am the administrator of my blog, and found that I can not change the author on the page that has already been published. With posts, there is no such problem. I can choose another author, but if I save it, I still have the same one.

Comment: Hmm, it should work the same as posts, I think. Do you have any caching setup? I know for some of my sites that use Redis caching, sometimes changing lesser used settings doesn't update the cache properly.

Comment: I'm using the wp supercache plugin, but I tried to disable it, it did not work. The interesting moment. I tried to restore the previous version of the page, then there was another author. The content has changed, but the author does not.